# create offline tiles using Geojson

Tags: leaflet

I want to use leaflet offline and create a world map using kml or geojson.

I have a geojson file of world and want to use that file to create a base map.
Something similar to openlayer 3 where we use kml to create a base map.
Regards,
Sidharth